# When emptyDir deleted for a completed pod of a job in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, storage, docker-volume

Per [Doc for Kubernetes Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir), "(emptyDir) exists as long as that Pod is running on that node". So when actually is emptyDir deleted for a "Completed" pod of a job?

I thought it's deleted when the pod is removed (`kubectl get pod` can no longer find the pod). But I'm wrong. Experiments show that an emptyDir is deleted as soon as the pod is completed.

Has anybody noticed this? Or is this version-dependent?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and it is strongly tied with Pod. This is not version-dependent.

**emptyDir:** emptyDir volume’s lifetime is tied to that of the pod, the volume’s contents are lost when the pod is deleted.

**Use cases:** An emptyDir volume is especially useful for sharing files between containers running in the same pod. But it can also be used by a single container for when a container needs to write data to disk temporarily, such as when performing a sort operation on a large dataset.